# A statistics question about drawing from a deck of double sided cards

Tags: statistics, game-theory, card-games

I have a deck of cards out of which 2 players randomly choose 6 each, and puts them on the table.

The cards are double sided and have 3 optional sides. A card can’t have the same the same option on both sides. So, if we have sides A, B and C, the cards are AB, AC and BC.

What should be the MINIMAL deck size to provide a good statistic spread, meaning each player will get every side at least 2 times, and avoid cases that all cards are facing up with the same side. There is an option of re-shuffle so even 80-90% chance of good spread is also acceptable.

Comment: Are you assuming that the three card types occur with equal frequency?  Also...since there are exactly three possible faces, I'd have thought that "at least $2$" meant "exactly $2$", no?

Comment: If you assumed the deck was infinite, and that each card type occurs with probability $\frac 13$ then there is a $\frac 13$ chance that any given card comes up with a given face.  Accordingly, the probability of getting exactly $2$ of each would then be $\binom 62\times \binom 42 \times \left(\frac 13\right)^6\approx 0.12345679$ (side note:  that number is amazing!), so increasing the deck size does not guarantee the result you want.

Comment: 1. I meant 2 faces of a type (A, B or C) out of 12 (drawing 6 cards)
2. Not sure what that means.

Comment: You said "each player will get every side at least $2$ times", right?  That would appear to mean that each player gets $AABBCC$ in some order.  If you meant something other than that, you should edit your post accordingly.

Comment: This is what I meant, yes. When you said "so increasing the deck size does not guarantee the result you want", you mean increasing from what? I asked what should be the minimum.

Comment: Ok...but then, as I said, "at least $2$" is the same as "exactly $2$" (as having more than $2$ of one face would force you to have fewer than $2$ of another).  My calculation shows that even for very large decks the probability of a player getting exactly $2$ of each face isn't very high.  So...what's the question?

Comment: Oh wait...I was assuming that you were only looking at the "face up" side but maybe I have that wrong.  If my first card is of type $AB$ with the $A$ side facing up, do you count that as having BOTH the $A$ and $B$ sides or just the $A$ side?

Comment: I need at least 2 A sides in any facing, and I don't want the all the face up sides to be of the same type

Answer (score 0):

Consider a deck of size $3N$ with $N$ each of $AB,AC,BC$.  There are, of course, $\binom {3N}6$ ways to choose $6$ cards from the deck.

How many of these avoid an $A$ completely?  Well, we need to get $BC$ six times so there is exactly $1$ way to do it.  Similarly for faces $B,C$ so the probability of missing some face completely is $\frac {\binom N6}{\binom {3N}6}$.  We remark that it is not possible to miss two faces completely.

Note:  in the large $N$ limit the probability of missing a face completely is $$3\times \left(\frac 13\right)^6\approx 0.004115226$$

What's the probability that we get only one $A$? Well, we need $BC$ five times and then the remaining card can be either $AB$ or $AC$.  As there are $6$ possibilities for the non-$BC$ card the probability of getting exactly one $A$ is $$2\times N \times  \frac {\binom N5}{\binom {3N}6}$$  Of course the probabilities of getting exactly one $B$ or $C$ are the same so we must multiply this by $3$.  Again we remark that it is not possible to get exactly one of more than one face.

Note:  In the large $N$ limit the probability of getting some face exactly one time is $$3\times 6\times \left( \frac 13\right)^5\times \frac 23\approx 0.049382716$$

The probability of getting all face up $A's$ is $$\frac {\binom {2N}6}{\binom {3N}6}\times \frac 1{2^6}$$

This is fairly small, in the limit the probability of getting all face up $A's$ is $\frac 1{3^6}\approx 0.001371742$ so the probability that we get all face up sides matching is three times this or about $0.004115226$

Thus, in the large $N$ limit the probability that a given player gets a "good" hand is $1-.057613169=0.942386831$

Now, to search for a minimal $N$ that passes some threshold you need to specify that threshold and use the explicit formulas I wrote out.